# Can't play the vod adaptive bitrate streaming from wowza to jwplayer in mobile devices

Tags: jwplayer, wowza

I am trying to vod  adaptive bitrate streaming from wowza to jwplayer. My smil file and video files are in same sub directory in wowza content folder. I am using wowza  4.2.0 and jwplayer 7.1.0. I have followed the wowza official documentation.
It is working all most all desktop browser. But it is not working in mobile devices(ios, windows 8, android 4.1+).
It gives error

```
error loading player no playable sources found
```

My jwplayer setup is

```
<script>
var playerInstance = jwplayer("myElement");
playerInstance.setup({
    playlist: [{
        sources: [{
                file: "http://host/vod/_definst_/smil:10/video.smil/jwplayer.smil"
            },{
                file: "http://host/vod/_definst_/smil:10/video.smil/manifest.f4m/jwplayer.smil"
            },{
                    file: "http://host/vod/_definst_/smil:10/video.smil/playlist.m3u8/jwplayer.smil"
            },{
                file: "rtsp://host/vod/_definst_/smil:10/video.smil/jwplayer.smil"
            }]
        }],
        primary: "flash",
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "16:9",
        autostart: true,
});
<script>
```

My Smil File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="">
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <switch>
        <video height="720" src="video_720.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" width="1280">
            <param name="videoBitrate" value="1729000" valuetype="data"></param>
            <param name="audioBitrate" value="194000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
        <video height="480" src="video_480.mp4" systemLanguage="eng" width="854">
            <param name="videoBitrate" value="783000" valuetype="data"></param>
            <param name="audioBitrate" value="128000" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
        <video height="360" src="video_360.mp4"  systemLanguage="eng" width="640">
            <param name="videoBitrate" value="471000" valuetype="data"></param>
            <param name="audioBitrate" value="12800" valuetype="data"></param>
        </video>
    </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

Would you please explain where the problem is? My questions are

1. How to streaming  vod  adaptive bitrate to all major desktop browser as well as mobile devices(ios, windows 8, android 4.1+)
2. If the video files and smil files are in another sub directory in content folder like(10/mp4/video.smil) then what will be the url for wowza vod streaming?

Comment: What do you see in the logs?

Comment: Are you able to playback the video for each protocol, without JW Player and without appending `/jwplayer.smil` at the end of the URL?

Comment: I have got "error loading player no playable sources found" in mobile devices(Android  4.1+, ios ). I have used wowoza  4.2.0 trial version and jwplayer 7 free version.  
Here is the live link http://doyel.priyo.com/show-video/1

Comment: You are going to have to provide a link.

Comment: I have pretty much the same issue - described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33764552/wowza-vod-app-with-jw-player-and-smil-file-not-working-on-mobile

I posted an example here: http://solsystech.com/ if it helps to reference