# Wowza VOD App with JW Player and SMIL file - not working on mobile

Tags: video-streaming, mp4, jwplayer, wowza, jwplayer6

I posted this in the wowza forums but have gotten a total of 0 responses, so I wanted to post here as well.  I haven't done a lot of media streaming work and I'm trying to close out some details of a VOD project that basically streams video to a website and have run into an issue with enabling the correct stream to go to the correct consumer (ex: android browser, chrome desktop browser, iOS, etc). I've cycled through a bunch of tutorials, forums, etc and can't find the right fix, including some of the questions here on SO...

Here's what I have set up:
On Wowza:
I have a VOD application set up

- content directory:
  ${com.wowza.wms.context.VHostConfigHome}/content/Weekends
- Playback types: MPEG-DASH, Apple HLS, Adobe RTMP, Adobe HDS, RTSP/RTP all
  enabled
- SMIL file: sopweekendsmil.smil (contents below)

SMIL file (in the test url posted at the bottom I'm currently using a different than described in this SMIL due to privacy - the below is the SMIL file for the actual project):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<smil title="">
    <body>
        <switch>
            <video height="240" src="SOP_priorities_240p.mp4" width="320">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="1000000" valuetype="data"></param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
            </video>
            <video height="360" src="SOP_priorities_360p.mp4" width="640">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="2000000" valuetype="data"></param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
            </video>
            <video height="480" src="SOP_priorities_480p.mp4" width="720">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="2000000" valuetype="data"></param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
            </video>
            <video height="540" src="SOP_priorities_540p.mp4" width="960">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="2500000" valuetype="data"></param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
            </video>
            <video height="720" src="SOP_priorities_720p.mp4" width="1280">
                <param name="videoBitrate" value="5000000" valuetype="data"></param>
                <param name="audioBitrate" value="48000" valuetype="data"></param>
            </video>
        </switch>
    </body>
</smil>
```

I have the above videos in the appropriate folder on the wowza server.

In the application webpage:
I'm using JW Player and have the following code to embed JW Player (version 6.9):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        fallback: true,
        width: 640,
        height: 480,
        sources: [{
            file: "http://[serverurl]:[port]/Weekends/smil:sopweekendsmil.smil/jwplayer.smil"
        },{
            file: "http://[serverurl]:[port]/Weekends/smil:sopweekendsmil.smil/playlist.m3u8"
        },{
            file: "http://[serverurl]:[port]/Weekends/smil:sopweekendsmil.smil/manifest.f4m"
        },{
            file: "http://[serverurl]:[port]/Weekends/smil:sopweekendsmil.smil/manifest.mpd"
        }],
        rtmp: {
            bufferlength: '10'
        },
        plugins: {
             'qualitymonitor-2':{}
         }
    }); 
</script>
```

(I don't really know what the qualitymonitor plugin does or if it works at all.  Seems to have no influence if I take it out...).
I tried a bunch of variations with the JW Player syntax, but this worked on the desktop browsers (Chrome/Firefox).  However, the only file/url that works correctly live seems to be the jwplayer.smil. None of the other ones work on the desktop browsers - I get a "No playable sources found" message if I take out the jwplayer.smil url to test the other ones.  Also, this isn't working in any way on any mobile browsers no matter what I try.  I've tried just a single file (ex: the .m3u8 smil url) and get the same error.

When I try the Test Players function in the Wowza server interface, the MPEG DASH test works correctly and the Adobe HDS works correctly (in chrome browser) but I can't seem to get those working outside of the Test Players.

I get the feeling that I'm missing some conceptual piece - do I need to create more actual files for the different consumers? Or is it possibly how I have JW Player set up? Or maybe something is being blocked?

Test URL: http://solsystech.com/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> UPDATE: I got this partially working - I updated the embed code to the
>   following:
>
> ```
> jwplayer("myElement").setup({
>       fallback: true,
>       width: 640,
>       height: 480,
>       androidhls: true,
>       sources: [{
>           file: "<?php echo $jwUrl; ?>",
>           type: "rtmp"
>       },{
>           file: "<?php echo $hlsUrl; ?>",
>           type: "hls",
>           "default": "true"
>       },{
>           file: "<?php echo $dashUrl; ?>",
>           type: "dash"
>       }],
>       rtmp: {
>           bufferlength: '10'
>       }
>   });
> ```
>
> I tried turning RTMP off completely, as I understand this should be
>   able to work without RTMP, but then nothing would play in chrome or
>   firefox for OSX, so when I added that back in and made HLS the
>   default, I was able to get the streams to play in mobile and desktop
>   browsers correctly.  If I have a different one as default, the mobile
>   browsers don't play the stream...Still trying to solve why nothing on
>   desktop browsers work if I don't stream in RTMP from Wowza...

Comment: An idea: which license do you have for JW Player? The free version does not support as much features as the full version does. The HLS playback in Flash mode is restricted.

Comment: Good point - I'm currently testing with the free version of 7.x.  My understanding is that it should try each stream in order until one works, which seems like, on mobile, it should try the rtmp, recognize it doesn't work, then try the next in line (assuming I take out the "default")...but it doesn't seem to do that...

Comment: I am not sure if it can play RTMP on mobile device without Flash support, which is quite rare case

Answer (score 0):

RTMP is a Flash format and will never play on mobile. HLS is the preferred format for maximum cross-device and cross-browser compatibility.

Comment: Hey Elon -
Yes, I get that - the issue I'm having is that if I take out the rtmp streaming options, the HLS does not appear to be streaming or accessible in some way...

Comment: Yes I believe with out HLS streams we always have rtmp subscribe set to true and bufferlength set to 0.1. So if you try just HLS by itself it fails? I don't think you need fallback option, also try adding subscribe:true to the rtmp option.